# How to make a whole div be a link to somewhere?

Tags: html

I have a div block that I want to be a link to somewhere.  I don't think I can just wrap it in an anchor tag because I don't think you're supposed to wrap an inline element around a block element.

Currently I just use javascript and it works fine except that the status bar doesn't show the destination URL when they hover over the div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing your div with an anchor, and making the anchor a `block` level element.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzyuS/1/)

HTML

```
<a href="http://awesomecows.com" class="blockLink">Block Link!</a>
```

CSS

```
.blockLink{
    display:block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but the div actually needs to be a div. It's got an images and some text in it.

Comment: Anchors may have images, and even text!

Comment: The following tags are valid within the <a> tag:
`acronym, applet, b, basefont, bdo, big, br, button, cite, code, dfn, em, font, i, iframe, img, input, kbd, label, map, object, q, s, samp, script, select, small, span, strike, strong, sub, textarea, tt, u, var`

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_a.htm

Comment: It's got some other divs in it too, I guess I could just make the inner divs block styled spans, but for some reason that doesn't feel right to me.  Would it be that bad if I just wrapped an anchor around the div?

Comment: A div is really a "non-tag"-- it has no intrinsic behavior besides being block level. What that means is that if you can do something with a div, you can probably do it with an a tag.

Comment: If you want the whole `block` to be a link, and be accessible by people who don't use Javascript / use screen readers, then make it an anchor. If you don't care about them, use Javascript. Wrapping an anchor around a div may have strange repercussions, depending on the browser - it'd be best not to do that. IMHO you should make them block spans, I'm not sure if that's the best solution but I've done it before...

Comment: @sam, if you need to use a div, use a div. what you could also do is inside the div, make an anchor that is the same size as the div and make it `display: block` like this answer says.

Comment: I needed to set the `width` and `height` of the `anchor` to `100%` for this to work. Since I had no info about the parent `Div`.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're saying you're just using javascript, but this is very easily done if you use jQuery:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(){
    window.location.href = [your url here];
});
```

As for the status bar, it won't show where it's going if you use this method. Of course you could put the URL in the `title` attribute of the div if you want...

Comment: Yea, I am using Jquery, and that code is pretty much what I have, but the problem is that the status bar doesn't show the destination URL so the user wouldn't know what page they will go to when they click. Not that big of a deal, but if I can get the status bar working too that would be good.

Comment: add function to the listern for the click envent to inject the text and you're done...

Comment: Might want to add `cursor:pointer;` to the div to indicate that it's clickable.